# What does slash mean in a SPARQL property path?

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikidata

In [one of the samples for querying Wikidata](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#US_presidents_and_spouses), I found the following query, which includes **p:P6/v:P6** in the line after **SELECT**. What does it mean?

```sql
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>

SELECT ?p ?w ?l ?wl WHERE {
   wd:Q30 p:P6/v:P6 ?p .       #-- This line
   ?p wdt:P26 ?w .
   OPTIONAL  {  
     ?p rdfs:label ?l filter (lang(?l) = "en") . 
   }
   OPTIONAL {
     ?w rdfs:label ?wl filter (lang(?wl) = "en"). 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Note that you should generally use **langMatches** to compare language tags, not `=`.  E.g., **langMatches(lang(?x), "en")**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the *SequencePath* flavour of a [SPARQL 1.1 property path](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#pp-language).

```
wd:Q30 p:P6/v:P6 ?p .
```

means that there is a triple `(wd:Q30, p:P6, ?x)`, and another triple `(?x, v:P6, ?p)`, without an explicit need to write (or name) the intermediate node `?x`. In other words, it says: "`?p` can be found by starting at `wd:Q30`, following property `p:P6`, and then property `v:P6`.